How can i predict mandarin pronunciation if i know a word’s canto pronunciation? Are there any patterns I should know about?
As a Hong Konger who speaks more Cantonese than Mandarin, I find it frustrating when I know a word’s canto pronunciation but not in Mandarin. I’ve tried to guess, but I often turn out inaccurate. Are there any patterns I should know to have a higher chance of getting my guesses accurate?

impossible lah

Reminds me of a story I once read, I'm imagining it has to have originated from Language Log but I am not having any luck finding it again now. There was a Cantonese speaker (interpreter?) who was trying to say "India" in Mandarin. In his mind he mapped, [dou ---> dao], since Cantonese dou usually becomes dao in Mandarin. He confidently went with his assumed pronunciation yin dao, but everyone just heard 阴道 instead!

我不敢用國語說排骨，因為怕別人會以為我說屁股

Found a summary from @jiebin in Zhihu. The article receives several up votes, but I don't know if they are correct because I can't speak Cantonese `_>`.

There are patterns, but they won't be apparent until you have a few hundred characters of Mandarin under your belt, and they probably will only get you an accuracy of about 70%.

Probably not..I'm in the reverse situation: I'm native Mandarin speaker and I'm learning Cantonese.
